# GitHub Pages, deploy error 'User cannot be authenticated with the token provided'

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I was deploying my site via github pages. but today when I try to update the site, github gives an error and cannot deploy. I updated Workflow a few times, but when it didn't work, I deleted it and still nothing changed. The error I get is: 'error pulling image configuration: download failed after attempts=1: unauthorized: unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.' How can I solve this problem?

My Repo: https://github.com/wraith4081/wafoen/
Error Log: https://github.com/wraith4081/wafoen/runs/7004088921?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: This is likely caused by a GitHub outage: https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. A few publishing actions seem have broken across users.